# Sticky Footer in website works on one page not another

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a footer to stay at the bottom of the webpage and allow for different amounts of content on different pages. It works on my index.html page but when I go to the "about" page the footer floats to the middle of the page. Any advice? the website is up at http://www.concept82.com/DISupdate/index.html and the trouble page is http://www.concept82.com/DISupdate/about.html. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you need to move your `#bottom` div outside of the `#wrap` div, so it's immediately following it. That'll get you most of the way there, but there still seems to be something on your index page that's keeping it from moving all the way to the bottom of the window.

Comment: Other than placing #bottom below #wrap, remove margin-top: -200px, why?
This will only cause problems depending on the page height. If you have to, use padding-bottom on this bottom div.

Comment: Thanks! It helps when there is a new pair of eyes when I've been working on this all day!

Comment: Cause that's how a sticky footer works, your wrapper div is set to have a min-height of 100%, which pushes your footer down at least the height of your window, then move the footer back up its own height. That keeps the footer at least at the bottom of the window when there's not that much content in the wrapper div. See Chris Coyier's demo at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of -200px margin-top on #bottom, do 200px. That will fix it.